# sqlite3 encoding in dask

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, dask

I have a `sqlite` db file that requires me to specify the encoding for correct parsing like this:

`conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)
conn.text_factory = lambda x: str(x, 'latin-1')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM mytable", conn)`

However, `dask` only seems to support the `dask.dataframe.read_sql_table` which doesn't support providing arguments to a sqlite3 connection (or so it appears).

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: In SQLite files, strings are never supposed to be encoded as Latin-1. You should fix the database.

Comment: How would you solve this problem with `pandas.read_sql_table`?

Comment: @MRocklin, Unfortunately I have never had to use the `read_sql_table` API. @CL., that's not an option :(

Comment: @MRocklin, it looks like providing a connection is supported in pd.read_sql_table. So, I'd probably use the same technique of setting the text_factory beforehand and then passing it to read_sql_table. `con : SQLAlchemy connectable (or database string URI)`